# Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.NETCore.App (>= 2.0.0)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I have tried everything to avoid this error and it keeps coming:

```
Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.NETCore.App (>= 2.0.0)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'.
```

**I downloaded and installed everything from this link:**
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/05/10/announcing-net-core-2-0-preview-1/

When I create a new asp.net core project that points to dotnetcore2.0 I get that error.

Why is this?

dotnet --version: 2.0.0-preview2-005905
**Here is the csproj file created by the cli or vs2017 template:**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <UserSecretsId>aspnet-SampleProj-FA293BE5-380F-47C2-994D-F7F2FAE390X9</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.0-preview1-24647" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <!-- ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.0-preview1-24647" />
  </ItemGroup -->

</Project>
```

Comment: do a google search on the exact error then `Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.NETCore.App (>= 2.0.0)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'`

Comment: I've done this and nothing...

Comment: What does `dotnet --version` print? What is in the csproj?

Comment: @Romoku dotnet --version: 2.0.0-preview2-005905 and please see the update to my post for csproj that dotnet new is creating...

Comment: @Romoku I tried changing Microsoft.AspNetCore.All version to exact same and still errors... I don't event think there is a .All package for 2.0.0-preview2-005905.. https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/download-archives/2.0.0-preview1-download.md

Comment: Sounds a lot like https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker-nightly/issues/8

Comment: @BlakeRivell From the `dotnet --version` you have preview 2 installed. Try uninstalling that and download the preview 1 sdk from [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/download-archives/2.0.0-preview1-download.md). Another possible issue is NuGet shows [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.All`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All/2.0.0-preview1-final) version as `2.0.0-preview1-final`.

Comment: @Romoku I think we are getting somewhere. I don't know why I did this, but I installed the latest from here: https://github.com/dotnet/cli. Any idea how I can uninstall?

Comment: @BlakeRivell For windows uninstall from control panel. Not sure on a Mac.

Comment: @Romoku also, do you know if the latest Vs2017 Preview is required to work with 2.0 or if the latest official vs2017 will be fine?

Comment: @BlakeRivell The announcement hints that you need 2017 preview. I haven't installed it to confirm.

Comment: @Romoku thank you for all the help. You were correct uninstalling all of the 2.0 stuff that I installed and reinstalling cleanly from that link worked. I installed a Preview2 version of the CLI that was messing everything up.

Comment: @BlakeRivell Posted a summary of the discussion as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> dotnet --version: 2.0.0-preview2-005905

Preview 2 is the latest .NET Core bits and may not work with the Preview 1 configuration.

To fix this uninstall the nightly bits and installed the [.NET Core Preview 1 SDK](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/download-archives/2.0.0-preview1-download.md) with [VS2017 Preview](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/preview/).

Additionally the ASP.NET and CoreFX teams have published more recent versions of Preview 1 libraries:

> 2.0.0-preview1-final

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <UserSecretsId>aspnet-SampleProj-FA293BE5-380F-47C2-994D-F7F2FAE390X9</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference
        Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All"
        Version="2.0.0-preview1-final" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <!-- ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference
        Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools"
        Version="2.0.0-preview1-final" />
  </ItemGroup -->

</Project>
```

See also:

- [Microsoft.AspNetCore.All](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All/2.0.0-preview1-final)
- [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools/1.0.0-preview2-final)